# Why does this C program compile without an error?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C, and I was playing with C. I typed a C code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n"); 
    \
    return 0;
}
```

Even though I used `\` knowingly, the C compiler doesn't throw any error. What is this symbol used for in the C language?

Edit:

Even this works:

```
"\n";
```

Comment: "\n"; it's a statement without any effect. It get completely ignored by the compiler and generates a warning. Try to compile with gcc -Wall flag that enable compile warnings.

Comment: Your main question has been answered several times. In reference to the part about `"\n";`, a c program is (more or less) a list of statements. A literal value (like `3`, or `"\n"`, or `"hamburgers"`) is a perfectly valid statement, even though it doesn't _do_ anything.

Answer (score 11):

The sequence backslash-newline is removed from the code in a very early phase (phase 2) of the translation process.  It used to be how you created long string literals before there was string concatenation, and is how you still extend macros over multiple lines.

See §5.1.1.2 Translation Phases of the C99 standard:

> The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by the following
>   phases.<sup>5)</sup>
>
> 1. Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation defined
>      manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for
>      end-of-line indicators) if necessary. Trigraph sequences are replaced by
>      corresponding single-character internal representations.
> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line
>      character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.
>      Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part
>      of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character,
>      which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such
>      splicing takes place.
> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens<sup>6)</sup> and sequences of
>      white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a
>      partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by
>      one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty
>      sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by
>      one space character is implementation-defined.
> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
>      `_Pragma` unary operator expressions are executed. If a character sequence that
>      matches the syntax of a universal character name is produced by token
>      concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined. A `#include` preprocessing
>      directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1
>      through phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.
> 5. Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and
>      string literals is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character
>      set; if there is no corresponding member, it is converted to an implementation defined
>      member other than the null (wide) character.<sup>7)</sup>
> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.
> 7. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each
>      preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are
>      syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.
> 8. All external object and function references are resolved. Library components are
>      linked to satisfy external references to functions and objects not defined in the
>      current translation. All such translator output is collected into a program image
>      which contains information needed for execution in its execution environment.
>
> <sup>5)</sup> Implementations shall behave as if these separate phases occur, even though many are typically folded together in practice.
>
> <sup>6)</sup> As described in 6.4, the process of dividing a source file’s characters into preprocessing tokens is
>   context-dependent. For example, see the handling of `<` within a `#include` preprocessing directive.
>
> <sup>7)</sup> An implementation need not convert all non-corresponding source characters to the same execution
>   character.

If you had a blank or any other character after your stray backslash, you would have a compilation error.  We can tell that you don't have anything after it because you don't have a compilation error.

---

The other part of your question, about:

```
"\n";
```

is quite different.  It is a simple expression that has no side-effects and therefore no effect on the program.  The optimizer will completely discard it.  When you write:

```
i = 1;
```

you have an expression with a value that is discarded; it is evaluated for its side-effect of modifying `i`.

Sometimes, you'll find code like:

```
*ptr++;
```

The compiler will warn you that the result of the expression is discarded; the expression can be simplified to:

```
ptr++;
```

and will achieve the same effect in the program.

Comment: In phase one, the "line end indicators" are implementation defined. Trailing white space could be considered part of the line end indicator, so in phase 2, the backslash would be followed immediately a a new-line, even though there was white space in the original input.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: In theory, you're correct.  In practice, my simplified statement applies to all the modern environments that I've ever heard of.  Do you have an explicit counter-example where the C compiler strips trailing blanks before doing backslash-newline splicing?  (The exact rules from the C99 standard are quoted; any comment I makes take second place to the standard and the bugs in the implementation being used.)

Comment: No, not a current one, though I seem to recall some ancient one that did it part of the time.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: There are rumours to the effect that on IBM mainframes where 'punched card' type records were used, then there were implied trailing blanks on the 80-column (72-column?) images, and those might be eliminated.  It's hard to be sure at this distance whether the blanks were 'really there' or not.  But that's about the only context I know of where it might once have been a possible issue.

Comment: Mainframes in general were oriented enough toward Hollerith cards that implied trailing spaces were fairly common (was definitely true on the Control Data machines I worked on). That's not what I was thinking of, though I suppose it *could* be related. What I'm (vaguely) remembering was on MS-DOS or CP/M, not a mainframe, but I can't remember much more than that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: +1 nice answer. You said in the answer that, `*ptr++;` this statement will be discarded and we should use `ptr++;`. But why does this statement `*ptr++;` should be discarded?

Comment: The `*` in `*ptr++;` is discarded.  It evaluates the pointer before the increment, and fetches the referenced value, and then discards the value (but increments the pointer).  The purpose of the statement is to increment the pointer, but someone added the star without thinking.  This is quite different from an expression such as `*tgt++ = *src++;` where the `*` is most definitely needed twice, or even `(*ptr)++` which does a different job, incrementing what the pointer points at.  The context is a complete expression consisting solely of `*ptr++`, in which the `*` is superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

The `\`, when immediately followed by a newline, is consumed by preprocessing and causes the next "physical" line to be joined to the current logical line. This is very important for writing long preprocessing directives, which have to be all on one logical line:

```
#define SHORT very log macro \
   consisting of lots and \
   lots of preprocessor \
   tokens
```

If you remove the backslash-newline sequences, it is no longer correct.  Some other languages from the Unix culture have a similar backslash line continuation syntax: the POSIX shell language derived from the Bourne shell, and also makefiles.

```
$ this is \
one shell command
```

About `"\n";`, that is a primary expression used to form an expression-statement. In C, expressions can be used as statements, and this is exploited all the time. Your `printf` call, for instance, is an expression statement. `printf("hello world\n")` is a postfix expression which calls a function, obtaining a return value.  Because you used this expression as a statement, the return value is thrown away. The return value of `printf`
indicates how many characters were printed, or whether it was successful at all, so by throwing it away, your program makes itself oblivious to whether the `printf` call actually worked.

Since the value of an expression-statement is discarded, if such a statement also has no side effects, it is a useless statement which does nothing (like your `"\n"`). But such useless expression statements are not erroneous. If you add warning options to your compiler command line you might get a warning such as "statement with no effect" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash \ get interpreted by the C preprocessor. It protect its following character (the new line character on your case).

Comment: Actually, it is the opposite of 'protect'; it ensures that both the backslash and the newline are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is simply escaping the next character. In this case, probably a line end (CR) character. Perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Escapes in C are enabled only inside strings.

Comment: Indeed, the preprocessor could only escape the line end character. Apologies for misleading. The answer by dAm2k above is more accurate.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Phase 2 of translation is: "Each instance of a backslash character (\\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines." (§5.1.1.2/1.1).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: that's not called escaping, neither in the standard (which refers to "escape sequences" only about character constants/string literals), neither in common parlance (I never heard that an escaped character is deleted). In this case, \ is the line continuation character, not an escape character.

Comment: My point was more about what was happening, than what people might or might not choose to call it.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash plus what is following it is an [escape sequence](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/27-chars/); "\n" together is the newline character (prints a newline). Another important one is "\t", for tab.

Comment: Escape sequences only occur in string and character literals.  The backslash in the question is not inside a string or character literal.