# Why does this compile without an error with Visual Studio and not GCC?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

Do you know why does this compiles without an error with Visual Studio (2012) and not GCC 4.7.2?

I am running some compiler tests on tricky source files.
According to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045847/why-does-this-c-program-compile-without-an-error), GCC should not error (error: expected expression before / token): any backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted as well as the new-line character.
So, this is equivalent to line splicing and should pre-processed as a single line.

```
#include                                        \
                                                \
    "my_header_\
file_example.h" /* this is a long trailing\
                comment */
```

Comment: Works here. Maybe you have \r\n problems?

Comment: Here is a bit about line continuation with backslash and translation phases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059549/c-multi-line-comments-using-backslash including in one of the answers the tricky bit about inadvertently adding a space after a backslash.

Comment: @djondal Posting the error message here would help in 1) understanding the issue 2) better search hits pointing here for someone else who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually have a end of line **immediately** after the `\`, the source if correct and should be accepted by a conformant compiler. The Draft for C99 language says in 5.1.1.2 Translations phases :

§2: *Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.
Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.*

This actually occurs in phase 2 **before** the preprocessor executes any `#include` so it should be accepted according to the standard:

§4: *Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
_Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. If a character sequence that
matches the syntax of a universal character name is produced by token
concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined. A #include preprocessing
directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1
through phase 4, recursively.*

Nevertheless, if there is a space between the `\` and the end of line, operation of §2 will not happen and there will be an error.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring the backslash/newline combination is correct in a macro (macro continuation). However, this occurrs in a string. The backslash is not followed by an `n` or other defined escape letter but by a `0x0d` or `0x0a` which is then taken literally into the string. So the file it tries to open is something like `my_header_0x0dfile_example.h`.

Btw, interesting to know the error it gives. As I suspect in the above, it complains about file not found, not about "illigal '\' in string literal".